# Consistency function in FSelector

Tags: r, feature-selection, consistency

I am new in this field and I read some articles on Feature Selection.
What does the "consistency" function do in R's FSelector package?
For instance,

```
consistency(Species ~ ., iris)
```

results in "Petal.Width"

Can you explain to me what this feature says in terms of consistency? Based on a paper I read,

**"A feature set {F1,..., Fn} is said to be consistent, when
Pr(C = c | F1 = f1,..., Fn = fn)=0 or 1
holds for all c, f1,...,fn. When a feature subset is consistent,
The inconsistency value is 0 and as an inconsistent feature
subset approaches the consistent state, the measure decreasingly
approaches 0."**

If we take Species as a class, how is Petal.Width the result of the consistency function on the iris dataset? For instance, Petal.Width =1.4 is found both in virginica and versicosis species. I think I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform feature selection with consistency in `FSelector`, values are discretized. This is rather common approach when using consistency.

After discretization, search through feature combination space is performed with `best.first.search` function. Search objective function is consistency measure (can be also calculated as 1-inconsistency). How to calculate inconsistency measure is ilustrated in image below (Liu's measure). I added link to original paper and believe that is enough information to get a grasp on the subject.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Package documentation:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FSelector/FSelector.pdf

Github repo:
https://github.com/larskotthoff/fselector/blob/master/R/selector.consistency.R

Used paper:
Arauzo-Azofra, A., Benitez, J.M. & Castro, J.L. J Intell Inf Syst (2008) 30: 273. https://doi.org/10.1007/s10844-007-0037-0